# Reading data from .csv file on MIPS

Tags: csv, assembly, mips, file-read, atoi

I have to develop a project where I must read data from a .csv file like this:

```
10,12.1
15,25.6
15,25.1
...
```

so I tried to read as follows:

```
.data 
    file: .asciiz "/home/gilson/Documents/test.csv" 
    .word 0
    buffer: .space 4
.text
main:
    #open file
    li $v0, 13
    la $a0, file
    add $a1, $zero, $zero
    add $a2, $zero, $zero
    syscall
    add $s0, $v0, $zero
    #read 4 bytes from file
    li $v0, 14
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    la $a1, buffer
    li $a2, 4
    syscall
    #print
    li $v0, 1
    lw $a0, buffer
    syscall

done: 
    li $v0, 16
    add $a0, $s0, $zero
    syscall

exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

and I had the following output:

```
824979505
-- program is finished running --
```

so I changed the print syscall to print string and the output was:

```
...
li $v0, 4
la $a0, buffer
syscall
...
```

```
10,1
```

as I could see he is reading from the file in character, not in number format. I would like to know if there is a way to directly read the numbers or do I have to necessarily use some procedure to convert from char to int?

Comment: its not char to int it is ascii to binary "10" = 0x31, 0x30 which you need to strip off the 0x3x part and convert.    ((0x31&0xF)*10) + (0x30&0xF) ultimately but that assumes you know these are decimal numbers not some other base (octal, hex, binary).

Comment: if this is purely decimal numbers then if new&0xF0 = 0x30 then accumulator *=10 accumulator+=new&0xF;  else (its a comma) save off the accumulator, zero the accumulator and cycle back to get the next character, else (newline or carriage return) handle that.

Comment: are you learning assembly or learning an algorithm or both?  ideally prototype it in some language you are strong in, and then port it to asm once debugged.  solving the algorithm problem separate from the language problem.  divide and conquer.

Comment: I'm learning assembly, thanks for the tip, that's what I was in doubt about, if it would have to be converted, now I've already implemented a procedure to convert and it worked.

Comment: understand that spreadsheets can generate more complicated csv files but deal with that experimentally (try putting double quotes and commas in a field then exporting and see what you get).  Just noticed you have decimal places was that intentionally or a typo in this question, if this is floating point not just integers then you need to deal with that which is similar to the same loop, but not exact.

Comment: likewise if you want to print the number out I dont know the syscalls off hand for the system you are running on but I assume that a print of an integer and a print of a floating point are different.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers which you are reading from the files will be in text format. You need to convert(typecast) them from text to number.